# Unable to load struts2-jquery-plugin

Tags: struts2, struts2-jquery-plugin

i am new in struts jquery, i will be getting the following error when the server started, struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.0.jar is there in lib directory.
please any one tell what is my mistake.

thanks.

```
Unable to load configuration. - [unknown location]
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:69)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init_PreloadConfiguration(Dispatcher.java:371)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.init(Dispatcher.java:415)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.init(FilterDispatcher.java:190)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:295)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4072)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4726)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: Unable to load jar:file:/D:/Spring_Full/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Mang/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.0.jar!/struts-plugin.xml - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:909)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadDocuments(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:154)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.init(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:121)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.DefaultConfiguration.reloadContainer(DefaultConfiguration.java:179)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration(ConfigurationManager.java:66)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: struts.apache.org - [unknown location]
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.DomHelper.parse(DomHelper.java:115)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider.loadConfigurationFiles(XmlConfigurationProvider.java:904)
    ... 25 more
```

Comment: What's the *full* stack trace?

Comment: thanks for replay sir, i will be add the trace with my question.

Comment: it says that `struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.0.jar` is not found. is it there in the class-path?

Comment: thank for replay Umesh Awasthi, but the jar is plasced in lib directory, and now i will be add full stack trace with my question.

Comment: Do you have internet connection on the server?

Comment: No sir, i did not have any internet connection on the server

Answer (score 2):

I know its been a long time since this question is asked, however i found a solution so thought will put it up here.

I faced the same issue with struts2-jasperreports-plugin-2.3.14.2.jar file which was failing to load an a server with **NO INTERNET ACCESS**. The issue was in the struts-plugin.xml file inside the jar it was pointing to http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd .

What i did was downloaded the struts-2.3.dtd file put it in the WEB-INF/lib folder. Then my war file started deploying without any issues.

Same issue with  struts2-jquery-plugin-3.6.0.jar file as well. same solution worked out.

Another alternative is that if you have already some other version of struts-2.x.dtd in you lib files, then you could edit the jar files change the struts-plugin.xml files and change the struts dtd file to the version you have.

Hope it helps.